# React-like refs in lit-html / lit-element?

Tags: lit-element, lit-html, lit

Does lit-html have by any change something like React's `ref` feature?
For example in the following pseudo-code `inputRef` would be a callback function or an object `{ current: ... }` where lit-html could pass/set the HTMLElement instance of the input element when the input element is created/attached.

```js
// that #ref pseudo-attribute is fictional
html`<div><input #ref={inputRef}/></div>`
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since lit-html renders directly to the dom you don't really need refs like in React, you can just `querySelector` to get a reference to the rendered input, are you using lit-html only or are you using it in LitElement? I can post a more detailed answer with an example matching what you need

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that this would be the answer to my question. Alan, please do me a favor and open a short answer, so you will get the credit for a correct anwer.

Comment: `ref` directive has been added to Lit 
https://lit.dev/docs/api/directives/#ref

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @WeiChing has mentioned somewhere above, since Lit version 2.0 you can use the newly added directive `ref` for that:
https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#ref

Answer (score 18):

In lit-element you can use [`@query`](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/blob/2338e8ca311225e8befbea7dda5b46bfa5ca6324/src/lib/decorators.ts#L211) property decorator.  It's just syntactic sugar around `this.renderRoot.querySelector()`.

```js
import { LitElement, html, query } from 'lit-element';

class MyElement extends LitElement {
  @query('#first')
  first;

  render() {
    return html`
      <div id="first"></div>
      <div id="second"></div>
    `;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to be the most succinct, direct, and useful.

Answer (score 5):

lit-html renders directly to the dom so you don't really need refs like you do in react, you can use `querySelector` to get a reference to the rendered input

Here's some sample code if you were only using lit-html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>lit-html example</title>
  <script type="module">
    import { render, html } from 'https://cdn.pika.dev/lit-html/^1.1.2'; 
    const app = document.querySelector('.app'); 
    const inputTemplate = label => { 
      return html `<label>${label}<input value="rendered input content"></label>`;
    }; 
    // rendering the template
    render(inputTemplate('Some Label'), app);
    // after the render we can access it normally
    console.log(app.querySelector('input').value);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app"></div>
  <label>
    Other random input
    <input value="this is not the value">
  </label>
</body>

</html>
```

If you're using LitElement you could access to the inner elements using `this.shadowRoot.querySelector` if you're using shadow dom or `this.querySelector` if you aren't

Answer (score 2):

```
-- [EDIT - 6th October 2021] ----------------------------
Since lit 2.0.0 has been released my answer below
is completely obsolete and unnecessary!
Please check https://lit.dev/docs/api/directives/#ref
for the right solution.
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Even if this is not exactly what I have asked for:

Depending on the concrete use case, one option to consider is the use of [directives](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/creating-directives).

In my very special use-case it was for example (with a little luck and a some tricks) possible to simulate more or less that ref object behavior.

```js
const inputRef = useElementRef() // { current: null, bind: (special-lit-html-directive) }
...
return html`<div><input ref=${inputRef.bind}/></div>`
```

In my use case I could do the following:

1. Before rendering, set `elementRef.current` to `null`
2. Make sure that `elementRef.current` cannot be read while the component is rerendered (`elementRef.current` is not needed while rendering and an exception will be thrown if someone tries to read it in render phase)
3. That `elementRef.bind` directive will fill `elementRef.current` with the actual DOM element if available.
4. After that, `elementRef.current` can be read again.

Comment: e.g. I converted react component A to litElement B. Is it a way to use A's internal methods. e.g. const myRef = useRef() <B ref={myRef}/>, myRef.current.innerMethod().

Answer (score 1):

For lit-html v1, you can define your own custom Derivative:

```js
import { html, render, directive } from "lit-html";
    
function createRef(){ return {value: null}; }
    
const ref = directive((refObj) => (attributePart) => {
  refObj.value = attributePart.committer.element;
});
    
const inputRef = createRef();
render(html`<input ref=${ref(inputRef)} />`;
     
// inputRef.value is a reference to rendered HTMLInputElement
```